# Social login options in MobileFirst (Worklight)

Tags: social-networking, ibm-mobilefirst, hello.js, mobilefirst-adapters

I need to implement social Login (facebook, Google, Twitter etc) in my hybrid application, which is being created using IBM MobileFirst Platform.

Which social login method is best for the mobilefirst hybrid application?

For Google login i am using hello.js with following code.

Is it possible to use the following code in MobileFirst??. The google will provide the response only through it's `Redirect URIs`. How can We get that response to MobileFirst hybrid application ??

```
hello.init({ 

    google   : GOOGLE_API_ID
},{scope: 'email' , redirect_uri:'redirect.html'});

hello.on('auth.login', function(auth){

    // call user information, for the given network
hello( "google" ).api("me").then(function(json){
    alert("Your email is "+ json.email);
}, function(e){
    alert("Whoops! " + e.error.message );
});
});
```

Please suggest....

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach would be to find good Cordova plugins that perform these login actions, as they would be the most suitable.

You will want to read about implementing Cordova plugins in MFP: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/adding-native-functionality/

And then try implementing various such plugins (google for them) until you find the right one for your app. If you encounter implementation difficulties, you should then open a new question with actual code we could help you with...

Facebook options to start with:

- http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/facebook-phonegap-cordova-without-plugin/
- https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Comment: Hi Idan, I just edited my question. Can you please have a look??